# pam sshd: run as root but get user ip

Tags: ssh, pam

I am trying to make a little script run by pam sshd

```
session optional pam_exec.so /foo/myscript
```

that would want to check the ip of the connecting user and if already in my database, do nothing, if not, write it in my database and send me an email. My problem is that if
a) I run this script as the user, I can read `$SSH_CLIENT` and find out the IP, but not write to the database (as it should be, since I don't want user messing with it)
b) if I run it as root I'm not sure how to find out about the current connections IP.

Is there a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: have you check all var know to `/foo/myscript` ? e.g. `env > /tmp/log`, you might have your pts/XX and remote IP.

Comment: This is what it sees, not much:
`LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
PAM_USER=[myusername]
PAM_RHOST=[myhost]
PAM_TYPE=open_session
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
PAM_SERVICE=sshd
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PAM_TTY=ssh
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
PWD=/
`

Comment: An append only file is a workaround, although still not the best one as that can be filled with garbage this way.